# Making the body of nav under the ehader in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

What I want to do is making the menu 1,2,3 under the header title not besides it :

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <h1>First Project in Bootstrap</h1>
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
     class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
   id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <div class="nav nav-stacked">
     <li><a href="#">Menu 1 </a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </div>

   </ul>

  </div>
 </div>
 </nav>
```

I want the Menu 1 under the the header title not beside it .. any suggestions ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19502/)**.

If you don't have access to the HTML code you could append it to the header when then page is ready :

```
$(function(){
    $('.navbar-header').append( $('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1') );
})
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(function(){
  $('.navbar-header').append( $('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1') );
})
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <h1>First Project in Bootstrap</h1>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
              data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                                                                            class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
         id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <div class="nav nav-stacked">
          <li><a href="#">Menu 1 </a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
        </div>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```